# MySQL dateformat %c does not return results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date-format

Why MySQL `dateformat` function does not fetch rows with a month in the query?

```
SELECT p.*  
FROM article AS p
WHERE p.parent_id = '6' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(p.backdated_on, '%Y %c') = '2015 8'  
GROUP BY p.article_id  
ORDER BY p.backdated_on DESC  
LIMIT 0, 6
```

I have one row with the `backdated_on` of `2015-11-08 19:10:04`

Any ideas why and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month is '2015 11':

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT('2015-11-08 19:10:04', '%Y %c');
+---------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('2015-11-08 19:10:04', '%Y %c') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2015 11                                     |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`'2015 8'` is matching date like `2015-08-dd ...`.

Answer (score 1):

If the date is `2015-11-08 19:10:04`, then the corresponding logic would be:

```
DATE_FORMAT(p.backdated_on, '%Y %c') = '2015 11'
```

However, it is a bad habit to compare dates using string functions.  Instead:

```
(p.backdated_on >= '2015-11-01' and p.backdated_on < '2015-12-01')
```